# WSO2 ESB : Invoking selective operation of an endpoint?

Tags: web-services, wso2-esb

I have created a WSO2-DS SOAP service with three operations, want to invoke a selective operation of that endpoint from a REST API ESB service.

Looks like the endpoint does not provide option to filter further based on operation.

Any help appreciated..

Thanks,
Wajid

Answer (score 0):

Header mediator should work ... header name="Action" value="soap action"